# Django - Limit choices to choose what are not chosen in admin form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model as below. I wonder how I can limit the choices for `self.fields['wife']` to all people who have the same `generation` as the current one that's on screen to be created (not saved yet), and also only limit to all that have not been chosen.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    GENERATION_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'First generation'),
        (2, 'Second generation'),
        (3, 'Third generation'),
        (4, 'Fourth generation'),
        (5, 'Fifth generation'),
    )

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    generation = models.IntegerField(choices=GENERATION_CHOICES, default=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')),
                              blank=False,
                              default=None)
    father = models.ForeignKey('self',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                               related_name='children_of_father',
                               limit_choices_to={'gender': 'M'})
    mother = models.ForeignKey('self',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                               related_name='children_of_mother',
                               limit_choices_to={'gender': 'F'})
    wife = models.ForeignKey('self',
                             blank=True,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             related_name='wife_of',
                             limit_choices_to={'gender': 'F'})
    husband = models.ForeignKey('self',
                            blank=True,
                            null=True,
                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                            related_name='husband_of',
                            limit_choices_to={'gender': 'M'})
```

And in admin.py:

```
class CustomPersonModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomPersonModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['wife'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(generation=???)


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomPersonModelForm
    list_display = ['generation', 'last_name', 'gender']
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not enought clear

Comment: Are you looking for something like [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)?